# Berglas not finding my google cloud credentials

Tags: docker, ubuntu, gcloud

I am trying to read my google cloud default credentials with berglas, and it says that:

```
failed to create berglas client: failed to create kms client: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

And I am passing the right path, and i have tried with many paths but none of them work.

```
$HOME/.config/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with [Berglas](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/berglas) (please include references) but the error is clear. Google's client libraries attempt to [find credentials automatically](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically). The documentation describes the process by which credentials are sought.

Since the credentials aren't being found, you're evidently not running on a Google Cloud compute service (where credentials are found automatically). Have you set an environment variable called `APPLICATION_DEFAULT_CREDENTIALS` and is it pointing to a valid Service Account key file?

The Berglas' [README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/berglas/blob/main/README.md) suggests using the following command to auth your user's credentials as Application Default Credentials. You may not have completed this step:

```bash
gcloud auth application-default login
```